# hide button in shindydashboard body until table is rendered

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have a shiny app where I load a file and a tabla is rendered, I want to hid a button in the body until the table is rendered. This button is going to save the filters in a file. I am using `shinySaveButton` from `shinyFiles` because I want the user to navigate until a folder and choose a custom filename

Here is the UI

```
header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
sidebarUserPanel("Test"),
sidebarMenu(
  id = "tabs",
  menuItem("Archivo variantes", tabName = "fileupload", icon = icon("table")),
  conditionalPanel("input.tabs == 'fileupload' ",
  shinyFilesButton("file", "Choose a file" , multiple = FALSE,
               title = "Please select a file:",
               buttonType = "default", class = NULL)#,
  )
 )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$style(type="text/css",
   ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
   ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"),

  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "fileupload",
        fluidRow(column(12,
          div(DT::dataTableOutput('tabla') %>% withSpinner(color="#0dc5c1"),  style = 'overflow-x: auto'))),
        fluidRow(column(2, offset = 0,
         shinySaveButton('save', 'Save filters', 'Save as...') )))

 )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)
```

And here is the server

```
## Server side
server = function(input, output, session) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)

  if (!exists("default_search_columns")) default_search_columns <- NULL

  volumes = getVolumes()
  volumes <- c(Home = fs::path_home(), "R Installation" = R.home(), getVolumes()())

   file_selected <- reactive({
     shinyFileChoose(input, "file", roots = volumes, session = session)
     if (is.null(input$file))
       return(NULL) 
     print(parseFilePaths(volumes, input$file)$datapath)
     return(parseFilePaths(volumes, input$file)$datapath)
   })   

   contents <- reactive({
     if (is.null(file_selected()))
      return()
     print(file_selected())
     df <- read.delim(file_selected(), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, as.is=TRUE)
     return(tidyr::separate_rows(df, Gene.refGene, sep = ";"))
   })

# Reactive function creating the DT output object
 output$tabla <- DT::renderDataTable({        
   if(is.null(contents()))
     return()
   datos <- contents()

   DT::datatable(datos, 
    rownames = FALSE,
            style = 'bootstrap', 
            class = 'compact cell-border stripe hover', 
            filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE), 
            escape = FALSE,
            extensions = c('Buttons', "FixedHeader", "Scroller"),
             options = list(
              stateSave = FALSE,
              autoWidth = TRUE,
              search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = TRUE),
              initComplete = JS(
                  "function(settings, json) {",
                  "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'font-size': '12px'});",
                  "}"),
              scroller = TRUE,
              scrollX = TRUE,
              scrollY = "600px",
              deferRender=TRUE,
              buttons = list('colvis', list(
                    extend = 'collection',
                    buttons = list(list(extend='csv',
                                        filename = 'results'),
                                   list(extend='excel',
                                        filename = 'results')),
                    text = 'Download'
                    )),
              FixedHeader = TRUE
            ), 
            callback = JS('table.page(3).draw(false); "setTimeout(function() { table.draw(true); }, 300);"')) %>% formatStyle(columns = colnames(.$x$data), `font-size` = "12px")

})


filtros <- eventReactive(input$tabla_search_columns, {
  str(input$tabla_search_columns)
  return(input$tabla_search_columns)
})

observeEvent(input$save, 
{
observe(
    if(is.null(input$tabla)) {
      shinyjs::disable("save")
    } else { shinyjs::enable("save") }
  )
})

observe({ 
  volumes <- getVolumes()
  volumes <- c(Home = fs::path_home(), "R Installation" = R.home(), getVolumes()())
  shinyFileSave(input, "save", roots=volumes, session=session) 
  fileinfo <- parseSavePath(volumes, input$save) 
  if (nrow(fileinfo) > 0) { 
    write.table(filtros(), fileinfo$datapath, row.names = FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=TRUE, sep="\t") 
  }  
})
```

}
     shinyApp(ui, server)

I am trying to use `shinyjs::disable` and `shinyjs::enable` but I can't make it work, the button `save filters` is shown before selecting a file. And I want to be hidden until the table is rendered

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I see a similar question on the shiny website that may point you in the right direction. https://community.rstudio.com/t/download-data-button-to-appear-only-when-data-is-fetched/1426/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shiny triggers the JavaScript event `shiny:value` when an output is rendered. So you can disable the button at the initialization of the app, and with the help of this JS event you can enable the button whenever the table is rendered. Here is a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

js <- paste(
  "$(document).ready(function(){",
  "  $('#save').prop('disabled', true);", # disable the 'save' button
  "});",
  "$(document).on('shiny:value', function(e){",
  "  if(e.name === 'table'){", # if 'table' is rendered
  "    $('#save').prop('disabled', false);", # then enable the 'save' button
  "  }",
  "});"
  , sep = "\n"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  shinySaveButton("save", "Save", "Save file"), 
  actionButton("go", "Render table"), 
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output[["table"]] <- renderTable({
    req(input[["go"]]>0)
    iris[1:4, ]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]